# Cannot change value of CGFloat within a View

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI, and I don't get what I'm doing wrong here but I cannot change a `CGFloat variable`.

Can you spot what am I doing wrong here?

```
struct SomeView: View {

    
    @State private var someWidth: CGFloat
    @State private var someHeight: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        Color.white
    
        /**
            Here the compiler throws an error:
        
            Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
        */
        self.someWidth = UIScreen.width

        
        Text("some Text")
            .frame(width: self.xwidth)
    }

}
```

The `width` variable isn't set directly like that, it goes through some checks and may change accordingly.
(otherwise I could just set the `UIScreen.width` to the `Text` frame)

Comment: *When* do you want to change it? You may try to use `onAppear` but everything depends on what is your goal.

Comment: I have updated the question. It's something around this implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI code makes a lot of use of "implicit return", that is `Color.white` is actually `return Color.white`.  You can see why your assignment code after the return, doesn't make sense. Even if it compiled, it wouldn't be executed.

You can make the compiler happy by using an explicit return:

```
var body: some View {
   self.someWidth = UIScreen.width
   return Color.white   
}
```

This will compile but give you a warning at run time that you are modifying the state while rendering the view.

You can execute code before the view is rendered using `.onAppear`:

```
var body: some View {
   ZStack {
       Color.white
   }.onAppear { self.someWidth = UIScreen.width }   
}
```

You haven't explained what you are actually trying to do, but you may want to look at `GeometryReader` rather than using `UIScreen`, or possibly inject the width from the super view via a parameter.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the reply. Basically I add a couple of views that will change their size (by some screen size calculations, like if there's only one view, it will be the screen size, if there's 2 views their size might be half of the screen size), based on how many views there displayed.
I am still wrapping my head around SwiftUI (haven't used it at all), though I just read of LazyVGrid and that may help me to achieve my goals, by playing with the `minimumWidths`

Comment: Yes, with SwiftUI you are almost always better letting the system adapt your layout rather than using procedural code to calculate sizes